# Raspberry pi 3 Serial Communication

Tags: serial-port, raspberry-pi3, display, uart

I want to connect an 5" HDMI display (26 header pins) to a Raspberry Pi 3. I also want to use `UART0 (Tx=GPIO14, Rx=GPIO15)`.
So I remapped `UART 0` to `Tx=GPIO36` and `RX=GPIO37` by using the command in `config.txt` file:

```
dtoverlay=uart0 ,txd0_pin36,rxdo_pin=37,pin_func=7  # alt 3
```

I also included the following commands in `rc.local`:

```
raspi-gpio set 14 ip
raspi-gpio set 15 ip
```

On entering `raspi-gpio get command`, I am getting `TXD0` and `RXD0` enabled at `GPIO14`, `GPIO15` and `GPIO36`, `GPIO37` respectively, but still serial communication is not working. Though it was working on `GPIO14`, `GPIO15`.

Now how to enable serial communication on `GPIO36`, `GPIO37`?

Comment: You've tagged your question with "python" tag. Post some of the code ([mcve])

Comment: I smell a hardware-related question here...

Comment: How does the HDMI display and `display` tag come into play in this question?  If it's irrelevant, then remove this clutter.